# Cleanest method to route with express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm using express to make a small web site with this code :

```
var package_express = require('express');
var app = package_express();

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html");
}).get("/login", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/login.html");
});
```

1) Is it the cleanest method to route my users ?
2) With this method, how can I have a "header.html" file, that will be include before all my pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your route handler in another file and import it

```
// my-route.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// About page route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('about page');
})

module.exports = router;

// index.js
var myRouteHandler = require('./my-route.js');
// ...
app.use('/prefix', myRouteHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand, the method to clean this code is to put it in an other file ? And I don't understand how you add a header file before send pages.

Comment: Not sure if I get it. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yap, with PHP, I can include a header.php file in all my pages, to don't write it in all of my page (and if I need to add a CSS file, I don't have to edit all of the headers, just the header.php file that is includes in all pages). I need to do the same with express :)

Comment: that have to do with the template engine. you can take a look at some of them like jade or pug.

Comment: @TuanAnhTran just fyi, jade and pug are the same thing.

Comment: Ah thanks. I dont know much about the frontend scene